# Considering best practices, can we use double unary operator ! in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For my understanding the unary `!` operator performs implicit type conversions, and are sometimes used for type conversion.

So basically the `!` operator converts its operand to a boolean and negates it.

Now:

```
!!x // Same as Boolean(x)
```

In fact:

```
!!'true' === Boolean('true') // true
```

So I am assuming both `!!x` and `Boolean(x)` perform the same action.

I would like to know:

- Do you know any caveats making my assumptions wrong?
- Which way should be preferred in term of good practice?
- Do you know any differences to be aware among different ECMAScript versions or Browser vendors?

Comment: Why do you keep referring to it as unary? Is there a binary ! operator?

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for your comment, for my understanding ! is a unary operator. I found this reference in JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition.

Comment: IMO it doesn't matter. They are the same in this case. I would prefer double-negate operator `!!` because it is less typing. Just bang bang and you are done.
But some would say that `Boolean()` casting function is more human readable.

Comment: beware of the string variant - `Boolean('false') === true` and `!!'false' === true` too.

Comment: the same thing is true for `!!'false' === true` because as far as I know strings with a value other than `''` are always true

Comment: @Anand it's not "the same as not using it". `var k = 'hey you'; console.log(k === !!k);` will print "false". This is all about type, the point is to get a boolean value based on the content of the operand, which might be anything from a number to an arbitrary object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Your assumptions are correct. That is exactly how it works and I'm
  not aware of any special care to be taken when using this.
- Speaking of good practice, you'll probably have as many people
  supporting the quick 'n "dirty" `!!` way as there are who would
  advocate using the `Boolean` function ; however, from my experience, it appears that
  `!!` is way more common in library code (look at the jQuery source,
  you have a lot of stuff like [`return !!locked;`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/callbacks.js#L192)). IMHO, it is sufficiently recognizable to be used without degrading code readability.
- This has all been standard for a very long time in ECMAScript ; I can't speak for old versions of Internet Explorer (before IE 8), but you can pretty much trust all modern browsers to behave the same in this case.

Useful references in the standard :

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2

Answer (score 3):

> Do you know any caveats making my assumptions wrong?

Your assumption is correct. Both `Boolean` function and `!!` has the same functionality.

> Which way should be preferred in term of good practice?

In terms of performance, Boolean is now globally faster than unary operators

JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/vj593auw/1/

> Do you know any differences to be aware among different ECMAScript
> versions or Browser vendors?

Boolean and unary operators are implemented from JavaScript 1.0, so they should be available in all browsers that supports JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.... could you please revise your answer? Even if related I am not sure if it answers specifically my question.

Comment: Also not sure if I your point regarding 'Boolean will consider it's parameter as an expression not as a value' is relevant as:
"Boolean() simply converts its argument to a primitive boolean value and returns that value."

as mentioned on JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition.

For my understanding and expression is evaluated to a value in order to be processed by Boolean() ex:
Boolean((function(){return 'false';})());

Comment: Please also consider reading ECMA-262 specification at 19.3.1.1. where only value is mentioned as argument of Boolean...Boolean(value)

Comment: @GibboK, expression is not a type, it means it will be evaluated at some point. On the otherhand, boolean is a type that uses either true or false.

Comment: @GibboK, I will modify my answer for your question

Comment: Nowadays, the performance of Boolean() is better in terms of performance